# Fmod unsatisfied link error while loading activity in android

Tags: android, fmod

I am getting unsatisfied link error exception when running on my acer liquid metal(2.3.6)

Exception

```
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1563)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1681)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:118)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:933)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load main: findLibrary returned null
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     at com.lingopal.TranslationScreen.<clinit>(TranslationScreen.java:1032)
06-20 18:47:30.184: E/AndroidRuntime(8121):     ... 15 more
```

I have libmain.so file in both directory armeabi and armeabi-v7a.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Often linker errors on Android are caused by incorrect or missing LoadLibrary calls. You should specify each dynamic library you are using in reverse dependency order in a static section of your Java code. For example:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("fmodex");
    System.loadLibrary("main");
}
```